# How to overcome UnicodeDecodeError while running command 'python manage.py celeryd —log-level=info'

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

When I try to run `python manage.py celeryd —log-level=info` below is the error that I get

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Reading articles on the web didn't really help, as they were far too much in detail for me to understand. Could someone please suggest how I could overcome this error.

I am using Python version 2.7.2

EDIT: Full Traceback of Error and locale settings.

```
(myenv)admin-iMac:example admin$ python manage.py celeryd —log-level=info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/admin/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/admin/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/admin/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 76, in run_from_argv
    self.handle_default_options(argv[2:])
  File "/Users/admin/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 86, in handle_default_options
    if '--settings=' in arg:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Line 86 of base.py from the above error, refers to the 'if' statement in the below method.

```
def handle_default_options(self, argv):
    acc = []
    broker = None
    for i, arg in enumerate(argv):
        # --settings and --pythonpath are also handled
        # by BaseCommand.handle_default_options, but that is
        # called with the resulting options parsed by optparse.
        if '--settings=' in arg:
            _, settings_module = arg.split('=')
            os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = settings_module
        elif '--pythonpath=' in arg:
            _, pythonpath = arg.split('=')
            sys.path.insert(0, pythonpath)
        elif '--broker=' in arg:
            _, broker = arg.split('=')
        elif arg == '-b':
            broker = argv[i + 1]
        else:
            acc.append(arg)
    if broker:
        self.set_broker(broker)
    return argv if self.keep_base_opts else acc
```

Below are locale settings:

```
(myenv)admin-iMac:example admin$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: The last line of the traceback is rarely enough to help diagnose the problem. Post the *full* traceback.

Comment: I would be you are running that command from a normal terminal that does not support non-ascii characters and somewhere in your program you have a `print some_Var` that is printing something outside of the ascii range ...

Comment: `0xe2` indicates a unicode character. Since none if it happens in your own code, it probably has to do with the fact that your `locale` is `UTF-8`, so your input from the command line it UTF. Try [setting it to `C`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmbx.html#glmar) and see what happens.

Comment: What version of Django are you running? Django-celery has `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, but Django versions below 1.6 do not have this. The djcelery commands are inherited from Django commands, so I wouldn't be surprised if those two will bite each other. Try upgrading to Django 1.6 if you don't have it; if that works, it's probably better than changing your locale.

Comment: Also, is `—log-level=info` an accepted flag? I've always used `--loglevel=INFO`. Can't check now though so I might be wrong.